# What it not printing hashes?

Tags: c, for-loop, nested-loops, cs50

Actually this is a quiz from first week of cs50 course. I thought I wrote the code correctly!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    n = get_int("Enter a number: ");

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("/n");
    }};

};
```

output should be:

```
#
##
###
####
and so on...
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code. can anyone help please.

Comment: `printf("/n");` -> `printf("\n");` Also looks like you have some extra `}` around

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thankyou

Comment: cs50.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop needs to loop `i` times for each `i`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
      printf("#");
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks. Edited.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

A couple of notes:

- `;` is not needed to end a `{...}` clause
- It is not `/n`, it is `\n` for a newline character
- `int main(void)` requires a `return` statement
- the statement:

  `for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){`

Should be:

```
for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
```

*Putting it all together*:

(Edited to address question in comments.)

```
int main(void)
{
    int n = 0;//initialize n to zero (< 1)
    while(n < 1 || n > 8)//stay in while loop until criteria is met
    {
        n = get_int("Enter a number between 1 and 8: ");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++){//n does not change, i does
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how can I add a restriction to the number of blocks to be drawn. For example between 1 and 8 ?

Comment: sorry for disturbance but can you check my code please.```#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    n = get_int("Enter a number between 1 and 8: ");

while(n > 1 || n < 8) {

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    };
return 0;
}};```     it show me this error: overlapping comparisons always evaluate to true
while(n > 1 || n < 8) {
      ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

Comment: @Mazenmohammed - compare what you just asked against the edit in my post above :)  The while is around the `int_get()` statement, then continues when criteria is met.